# How to highlight a list of cells (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have list of cells in Excel (A12, B54, C100...) all written in the first column of an excel document. Is there any way to highlight all the cells automatically in another sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little macro will go down column **A** of *Sheet1* and get the addresses and color those cells in *Sheet2* Yellow:

```
Sub dural()
Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(r.Value).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    Next r
End Sub
```

In *Sheet1*:

[image]

Result in *Sheet2*:

[image]

*Notes:*

In this demo, we are assuming that the values in column **A** of *Sheet1* are **constants**.  *(if they are formulas, SpecialCells() will need to be changed.)*